# Weird behaviour center button autolayout iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm using `XCode 6.1.1`.

I have this button with autolayout to center in x and y but it shows that is going to appear in the top/left corner:

[image]
[image]

Why?

What's the purpose of the align center y/x to parent view?

Comment: may be because constraint for super view is not set properly

Comment: Did you see any warnings ? If yes please paste that also

Comment: It was because the parent view didn't have any autolayout, thanks

Comment: WC, And its my personal experience, Do not ignore any warnings during autolayout, it will cause strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to set a width and height constraints in order for the AL to determine where to put the element.

Also, check that the parent (if there is one) is laid out properly.